# Rate of change in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

I need help with the following problem:
the temperature in a given point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by $T(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$. And a particle's position at a point in time $t$ is given parametrically by $(x,y,z) = (t, t^2, t^3)$.

I'm given the task of finding the rate of change in temperature when $t = \frac{1}{2}$. Since the rate of change is given by the derivative, my guess would be to find the partial derivatives for $x$, $y$, and for $z$ and later substitute the coordinates $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8})$. But I wouldn't know exactly how. Any help is most welcome.

Comment: What do you know about the chain rule?  $\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \dots$

Comment: Is this to say that I can find the rate of change by doing $T(t) = (t)^2 + (t^2)^2 + (t^3)^2 = t^2 + t^4 + t^5$ and finding the derivative of said function?

Comment: You don't need to do *both*.  Either one will do.  Btw, note that $\deg T=6$ w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: Oh right, $2 \cdot 3 = 6$

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use Chain Rule.

\begin{align*} \frac{d g}{dt} = d_{c(t)}T \cdot d_t c  = \begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x} &\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}_{c(t)}\  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{dx}{dt} \\ \frac{dy}{dt} \\ \frac{dz}{dt}\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}